# Firebase getting value returns NULL value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a database in this format: [image]

I need to be able to get the `name`, `price` and `quantity` after I search the database for the barcode.

I tried something like this:

```
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("ProductData");
    UserId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

public void searchProduct(String barcode){
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("Products").child("barcode").equalTo(barcode).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("DBVAL", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the output:

> D/DBVAL: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that result because you aren't using the correct query. Besides that, there is no node in your database named `DataUsers`. To get all children that contains a particular barcode, please use the following query:

```
Query barcodeQuery = mFirebaseDatabase.child("ProductData").child("Products")
        .orderByChild("barcode").equalTo(barcode);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            int price = ds.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
            int quantity = ds.child("quantity").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + "/" + price + "/" + quantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
barcodeQuery.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

See, I have added in this query both nodes `ProductData` and `Products`, and then I order all children by `barcode` property and used `.equalTo(barcode)`.

Comment: Great answer Alex! You might want to also add the loop over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` in your answer, as that is the next stumbling block for many developers when they get started with Firebase queries.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, puf  Just edited my answer to make it complete.

Comment: I get this error: W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "barcode"' at ProductData/ProductData/Products to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Comment: I assume that it's caused because of this: mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("ProductData");

Comment: Anyway. It worked. That was because of this: mFirebaseDatabase.**child("ProductData")**.orderByChild("barcode"). I had to remove the bolded section. Thank you very much, sweet romanian!